# Submit Button is not functioning using Python Flask and AJAX

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, submit

So I have an edit page feature for my app and the submit button doesn't seem to work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've made sure that all the variables line up with one another. Once I click submit, it does nothing. It doesn't notify me that it was successful nor does it give me an error message. And when I check the database, the information hasn't been updated at all.

This is my HTML:

```
     <div  class="col-xs-4" >
                <input type="text" id="e_firstc" name="e_firstc" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name"><br>
                <input type="text" id="e_lastc" name="e_lastc" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name"><br>
                <input type="date" id="e_birthdatec" name="e_birthdatec" class="form-control" placeholder="Birthdate"><br>
                <input type="number" id="e_agec" name="e_agec" class="form-control" placeholder="Age"><br>
                <input type="text" id="e_disorderc" name="e_disorderc" class="form-control" placeholder="Diagnosis"><br>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="edit_child();">Submit</button>
                <br>
                <br>

            <script src="jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
                <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                <script src="app.js"></script>

        </div>
```

app.js:

```
    function edit_child() {
var first_name = $('#first_name').text();

$.ajax(
    {
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/childinfo_edit/'+first_name+'/',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'e_firstc': $("#e_firstc").val(),
            'e_lastc': $("#e_lastc").val(),
            'e_birthdatec': $("#e_birthdatec").val(),
            'e_agec': $("#e_agec").val(),
            'e_disorderc': $("#e_disorderc").val(),
        }),
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (e) {
        },
        success: function (resp) {
            if (resp.status == 'ok') {
                alert("successfully updated")
            }
            else {
                alert("ERROR")
            }

        }
    });
```

}

And the app.py:

```
    @app.route('/edit_childinfo/<string:first_name>/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
```

def edit_child(first_name):

```
params = request.get_json()
e_firstc = params["e_firstc"]
e_lastc = params["e_lastc"]
e_birthdatec = params["e_birthdatec"]
e_agec = params["e_agec"]
e_diagnosisc = params["e_diagnosisc"]


res = spcall("edit_child",(first_name, e_firstc, e_lastc,e_birthdatec, e_agec, e_diagnosisc), True)

recs = []

for r in res:
    recs.append({"e_firstc": r[0], "e_lastc": r[1], "e_birthdatec": r[2], "e_agec": r[3], "e_diagnosisc": r[4]})
return jsonify({'status': 'ok', 'entries': recs, 'count': len(recs)})
```

Comment: only thing i can see is the `url` you are sending to, try {{url_for('edit_child', first_name= first_name)}} in that part, if it worked, let me now to make it an answer, you can check for the parameters being sent or not, by using `developer tools`(ctrl+shift+q in firefox)

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: did you check with developer tools if your js was working? i think you have bad path to your jquery too... you should check it step by step in developer tools to see witch part isn't working